# Angular 10 NgForm

Tags: angular

I am developing a master details form for my company. I am getting the  error mentioned below.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts:2867:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/forms) which declares NgForm has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

2867 export declare class NgForm extends ControlContainer implements Form, AfterViewInit {
                          ~~~~~~
```

I have mentioned the code in app.modules.ts below

```
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DataTablesModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    NgForm,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
],

<from #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" *ngIf="service.formData"> 
[(ngModel)]="service.formData.materialRequisitionNo" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

The code for materialrequiresition.ts is below

```
    export class MaterialRequisitionComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(public service: MaterialRequisitionService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
}
resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form = null)
      form.resetForm();
      
    this.service.formData = {
        materialRequisitionNo: '',
      workOrderNo: '',
      department: 0,
      id: 0,
      approvedBy: 0,
      requestedBy: 0,
      requsitionDate: null,
      workOrderDate: null,
      requestItemList: [],
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo

```
<from #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" *ngIf="service.formData">
```

says `from` not `form`